# Face database in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a database full of images, and want to build up a database of all the people in it. I'm doing it in python, and using opencv I can already detect where the faces are, now I just need a way to detect if a face is the same as one already in the database, and the add it to their 'profile', and if not create a new profile. All the facial recognition libraries i can find only compare two faces, but I rather want it to calculate a certain ID or something along those lines.